# Change the section index background colour

Tags: swift, uitableview

Currently I am using `table.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clear` which makes the section index semi-transparent, causing what you can see in screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to **remove the semi-transparent overlay**, which ends above the home button area on iPhone X. Another option is to extend the section index background throughout this area and set a non-transparent colour, because this design on rounded display looks really weird.

Any ideas how to do this?

---

**EDIT**
The point is, if I change the background colour to any value, the area near home button remains semi-transparent **while scrolling**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't see any section index in your pictures.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for bad color scheme, I will update screenshots with more colorful ones in a moment. meanwhile, the section index is **on the right side of the pictures**, it's a semi transparent vertical bar.

Comment: Set the background color of your table view to the background color of your cells.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez you can see what it looks like on the second screenshot and that's the point. It will change all the colour excluding the home button area, which remains semi transparent gray

Comment: Seems like you fixed it. For future reference I would suggest using the View Hierarchy Inspector to find out exactly which view is looking odd.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez you are right, but did't find any solution there...

Answer (score 2):

**FIXED**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt path: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: path)
    let data = ...
    cell.textLabel!.text = ...

    // here it comes
    cell.contentView.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return cell
}
```